# Retrieve Data from ComboBox selection to TextBlock

Tags: c#, combobox, win-universal-app

I have populated the comboBox with the Data from SQLite
Here's how I did it.

```
conn.CreateTable<AccountName>();
var query = conn.Table<AccountName>();
myComboBox.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

So when I try to retrieve the selected ComboBox Item to a TextBlock, I get the output as

```
'Apps.Models.AccountName'
```

How can I retrieve the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer by using this code.

```
        Demo.Text = ((AccountName)myComboBox.SelectedItem).AccName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for `SelectedValue`, SelectedItem Gets currently selected item in the ComboBox. Use either of these.

```
comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

or

```
comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: I have no problem adding values to the ComboBox but When I try to retrieve the data to a textblock    eg:  Demo.Text = AccountName.SelectedItem.ToString();  It gives the output as  "'Apps.Models.AccountName"

Comment: @JijoBose Sorry I have overlooked the question, updated now please check.